# Regex or if loop ....for password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, passwords

I want to validate password in which it should accept

- At least 2 numerical,
- At least 1 upper-case,
- At least 1 lower-case,
- At least 1 symbol.
- And no space.
- Minimum length of password should be 8 characters

Like shown below

- asdA1@#2.
- 1Aas&3%A
- 21asdA@!

Numerical symbols not necessarily have to be together.

It can be anywhere, and separated.

Comment: "You want", OK. But did you try something by yourself?

Comment: Small hint: people are lazy. So if you force them to use a certain type of password, they will fastly be annoyed and than they use Pa$$word1

Comment: Please see the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section of the Help Center and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[&@%#!])[^\s]{8,}
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/llmVBW/1)

Comment: Though not important, it can be done in half the steps: https://regex101.com/r/y1Bhbk/1 (+1 nevertheless).

Answer (score 0):

I would split all the conditions to seperated boolean methods, and one validatePassword method that will call all the condition methods, without regex.
code should be readable and easy to maintenance.

Tommorow you might want to change something in the conditions, it will be hard to change the regex and you will have to test all the schenarios over again.